# Flutter 308 Redirecting.... response

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http

this is the flutter code for http post request. this endpoint send a email verification link to the entered email. now instead of 200 ok im getting this -
I/flutter (13736): Response status: 308
I/flutter (13736): Response body: Redirecting...

```
try {
      var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse('i entered my api endpoint here correctly'),
          body: jsonEncode({
            "name": name,
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
          }));

      print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');
    } catch (e) {
      print('An Error occured : $e');
    }
```

I tried to call the api again on getting 308 response status code. still not working

Comment: means, the endpoint is redirected to a new one. try the same from a rest client. if it still gives 308, contact your backend developer